# App crashes and gives this error java.lang.NullPointerException: null cannot be cast to non-null type android.content.Context

Tags: android, kotlin

i am new to android development,any help will be really appreciated,
here is the code

```
class Dashboard : Fragment() {
lateinit var recycle:RecyclerView
lateinit var reLayout:RecyclerView.LayoutManager
lateinit var RecObj: AdapterData
var bookInfoList = arrayListOf<Book>()


  override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dashboard, container, false)
    recycle = view.findViewById(R.id.recyle)
    reLayout = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
    val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(activity as Context)
    val url = "http://13.235.250.119/v1/book/fetch_books"



val JsonRequest = object : JsonObjectRequest(
        Request.Method.GET,
        url,
        null,
        Response.Listener{
            val success = it.getBoolean("success")
            if(success){

                val jsonarray = it.getJSONArray("data")
                for( i in 0 until jsonarray.length()){


 val jsonobj = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i)
                        val bok:Book = Book(
                        jsonobj.getString("book_id"),
                        jsonobj.getString("name"),
                        jsonobj.getString("author"),
                        jsonobj.getString("rating"),
                        jsonobj.getString("price"),
                        jsonobj.getString("image")


                    )
                bookInfoList.add(bok)
                RecObj = AdapterData(activity as Context,bookInfoList)
                recycle.adapter = RecObj
                recycle.layoutManager = reLayout



            }


        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(activity as Context,"Error",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    },
    Response.ErrorListener{
        println("Error is $it")
    }
)
{
    override fun getHeaders(): MutableMap<String, String> {
        val headers = HashMap<String,String>()
        headers["Content-type"] = "application/json"
        headers["token"] = "9bf534118365f1"
        return headers
    }
}
  queue.add(JsonRequest)
return view

}
}
```

My app crashes and I am getting this error in logcat console.

```
: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000
E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
PID: 3804
    java.lang.NullPointerException: null cannot be cast to non-null type android.content.Context
        at fragment.Dashboard.onCreateView$lambda-0(Dashboard.kt:69)
        at fragment.Dashboard.$r8$lambda$j-5MnkJzaOGydqDeYcnojQDDSnA(Unknown Source:0)
        at fragment.Dashboard$$ExternalSyntheticLambda1.onResponse(Unknown Source:4)
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonRequest.deliverResponse(JsonRequest.java:100)
        at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:102)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:899)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:238)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7835)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:984)
```

Other thing to mention is when i put this code

```
RecObj = AdapterData(activity as Context,bookInfoList)
                    recycle.adapter = RecObj
                    recycle.layoutManager = reLayout
```

at the start of onCreateView function, my app works perfectly fine, but ofcourse then i cant pass the data from the json object. Any idea what i am doing wrong?

Comment: its solved, after some sweating and looking at the code, i tired to change the argument in the function Adapter as activity as Context?, hope this helps someone

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow and android community. First of all, I would like to highlight that it has been years since volley is used. Your first choice should be Retrofit. Second, initialize adapter in onViewCreated rather than onCreateView. Third, I doubt adapter first argument